# Class Responsible for Connection Output

Tags: java, netty

What class is responsible for the output in console on connection:

```
13:51:20 [INFO] [id: 0xe0961ca4, /127.0.0.1:64961 => /127.0.0.1:8000] OPEN
13:51:20 [INFO] [id: 0xe0961ca4, /127.0.0.1:64961 => /127.0.0.1:8000] BOUND: /127.0.0.1:8000
13:51:20 [INFO] [id: 0xe0961ca4, /127.0.0.1:64961 => /127.0.0.1:8000] CONNECTED: /127.0.0.1:64961
```

or is there a way to suppress this?

Comment: Should be some class managing the connection in the netty.jar you are using. Posting you code that manage connections will help to give a proper answer.

Comment: A simple `grep` on `netty` sources would give the answer, e.g. UpstreamChannelStateEvent.